# Trigger @change of v-text-field in Capybara test

Tags: rspec, capybara-webkit, vuetify.js

I have this spec:

```
checklist_item_element.fill_in 'description', with: 'Changed description'
page.find('body').click # to blur the input field
checklist_item.reload
expect(checklist_item.description).to eq('Changed description')
```

I have this template:

```
v-text-field.habit-card__habit-checklist__checklist-item-description(
    name="description"
    v-model="checklistItem.description"
    data-vv-name="description"
    @change="saveChecklistItem(checklistItem)"
)
```

I am using the `webkit` driver of Selenium. The last `expect` always fails because `description` is still the old value instead of `Changed description`.

If I am doing the same actions on my own using the Chrome browser it works absolutely fine.

I guess the `@change` is not triggered. Am I right and if yes what could I do to achieve it?

Comment: If you sleep for a couple of seconds after the `click` does the test then pass?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Sorry I didn't tried it. I have now changed my spec as described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any actions triggered by browser actions (`fill_in`,`click`, etc) are generally not completed when those methods return since Capybara and the drivers have no way of knowing what actions will or will not trigger further actions on the page, nor whether those actions triggered would be relevant to anything the tester is doing.  This is why all of Capybaras finders/matchers have waiting/retrying behavior built-in in order to synchronize with changes happening in the page.  This is also partly why  doing direct database checks in feature tests is generally a bad code smell since it doesn't provide any way to synchronize with the page.

If you really need to do (or insist on doing) direct database checks then you need to put an expectation before them (after the browser action that triggers them) for whatever visual page change indicates to the user the action has completed. If there is no visual page change (generally indicates a bad UX) then all you can really do is sleep for some amount of time (or potentially use one of the gems that provides general purpose waiting spec matchers (waiting_rspec_matchers, etc)).

Comment: You are right. I changed the spec to check for existing success notifications instead if checking the model itself.